# NameError: ObjC Class 'b'NSEvent'' couldn't be found. - PyAutoGui

Tags: python, importerror, pyautogui

I installed `pyautogui` recently, using `pip3 install pyautogui`. This worked and I received no error on installation. But when importing the module as shown below.

```
import pyautogui
```

I was kindly greeted with this error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "a.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pyautogui
  File "/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 241, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
    NSEvent = ObjCClass('NSEvent')
  File "/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rubicon/objc/api.py", line 924, in __new__
    ptr, name = cls._new_from_name(name_or_ptr)
  File "/Users/name/.pyenv/versions/3.8.2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rubicon/objc/api.py", line 827, in _new_from_name
    raise NameError("ObjC Class '%s' couldn't be found." % name)
NameError: ObjC Class 'b'NSEvent'' couldn't be found.
```

What am I doing wrong here? Did I not install it correctly? Seems like the [docs](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) import the module like I am.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um. I gave the following a try.

```
import AppKit
import pyautogui
```

No error message came.
I tested this answer.

```
import AppKit
import pyautogui
screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
print((screenWidth, screenHeight))
```

I got no error and received the correct output.

```
(1440, 900)
```

Comment: An explanation to why this worked would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue when running Python 3.6.8 on macOS Big Sur 11.4 (20F71). Installed fine with no errors, but getting the same exception when importing `pyautogui`.

However, I tried installing and running with Python 3.8.8 had no problems.

I was getting errors when attempting to `pip3 install pyautogui` previously, and had to fiddle with it until everything said it installed successfully. To be sure it wasn't some issue with my python environment, i created a new venv for 3.6 and got the same issues. Specifically, it seems to be choking when attempting to install `pyobj`. All my software is current as I just updated everything a few says ago. Current XCode version is 12.5, build 12E262

```
    clang -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -I/usr/local/opt/sqlite/include -I/Users/lpettit/Desktop/Luke/venv/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.6.8/3.6.8_5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c Modules/objc/module.m -o build/temp.macosx-11-x86_64-3.6/Modules/objc/module.o -g -fexceptions -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wformat=2 -W -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wnested-externs -W -Wno-import -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Werror -I/usr/include/ffi -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX11.3.sdk -DPyObjC_BUILD_RELEASE=1103
    clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/lib' [-Werror,-Wunused-command-line-argument]
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/lpettit/Desktop/Luke/venv/bin/python3.6 -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/zm/vmrhx84s2033swkpff49kn_40000gn/T/pip-install-deunlwzj/pyobjc-core_d8cfbbc58c52474aa7935601a9dd5cd8/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/zm/vmrhx84s2033swkpff49kn_40000gn/T/pip-install-deunlwzj/pyobjc-core_d8cfbbc58c52474aa7935601a9dd5cd8/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /private/var/folders/zm/vmrhx84s2033swkpff49kn_40000gn/T/pip-record-5iunioef/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /Users/lpettit/Desktop/Luke/venv/include/site/python3.6/pyobjc-core Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'd suggest to migrate to python3.8 or 3.9 if possible. I'm not 100% convinced that the xcode version is really the problem and not just a symptom, but you could try and rollback your c compiler version and see if it helps.